# The existence of more than one word given in parameter, in files content?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to find a command on bash shell, which allows me to verify if all words given in parameter(in the list `$*`), exist in the current directory I'm in.

Exemple, if I execute this command:

```
bash ./exp_quotes.sh hadir Trex blabla
```

How to test the existence of the tree words in one command, and get a value of 1 or 0 as `$?` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "in a folder" and "existence of a word"? Do you mean match file names in the folder? Or match contents of the files in the folder? Something else?

Comment: Hello, I mean match contents of the files in the folder :)

Comment: [grep](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/grep1.html)?

Comment: yes, but how can I do it for all words one time, and have a unique value of $?

Comment: Start by reading the man page? It tells you all you need to know - `grep` can take a pattern, can search multiple files and can return a value.

Comment: What I want to do, is for exemple: grep -i $* file

Comment: I know what you want to do. I've told you that grep can do it. Please go and try it. Show your best attempt and explain what issues it has if you have difficulties.

Comment: I'm really trying, but It gives me 0 all the time, why ?

Comment: @IdelHamza you want to check that all 3 words (hadir Trex blabla) exist in `file` ?

Comment: @IdelHamza All words or any words?

Comment: All words at the same time, using $*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make grep do all the job of searching for all patterns.
You just need to concatenate all of them together with `|`, as this:

```
$ echo "$(IFS=\|; echo "$*")"
hadir|Trex|blabla
```

Then, you just need to use grep to do the search:

```
$ cat ./exp_quotes.sh
#!/bin/bash
file="$1"
grep -qE "\"$(IFS=\|; echo "$*")\"" "$file" && exit 1 || exit 0
```

Change the permissions (to run) of the script:

```
$ chmod u+x ./exp_quotes.sh
```

And execute it with the filename first and the patterns:

```
$ ./exp_quotes.sh file hadir Trex blabla
```

This may be used even for patterns with spaces:

```
$ ./exp_quotes.sh "file name with spaces" "a hadir with spaces"  Trex blabla
```

---

If what you need is to list the files that do contain all the words, use this:

```
$ cat ./exp_quotes.sh

#!/bin/bash
grep -lE "\"$(IFS=\|; echo "$*")\"" *
```

---

To have an exit code of 0 if "at least one word is found" is the same as "exit 0 if one word OR other is found"

That would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
infile="$1"
grep -qE "\"$(IFS=\|; echo "$*")\"" infile && exit 0 || exit 1
```

Comment: Thank you, what if I want to have the value of $?, because I want It to be at 1 if ALL WORDS are NOT found, and 0 if at least one DOES.

Comment: @IdelHamza Read the last part (edited) in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if *all patterns* exist in `file`,
you can write `exp_quotes.sh` like this:

```
#!/usr/local/env bash

for arg; do
    grep -q "$arg" file || exit 1
done
```

This script will exit with 1 (failure) if any of the arguments is not in `file`.
Otherwise it will exit with 0 (success).

Comment: Sorry, can I know what `-q`does ?

Comment: @IdelHamza it suppresses the output of `grep`. It seems you don't want its output, only its exit code. If you want its output too, you can safely remove the `-q`.

Comment: Actually, what I want is to know if at least ONE word exists in files I have, otherwise ...

Comment: So I think I need the output, but even when I remove `-q`, I don't have any output